# Maven fails to start embedded Tomcat container when running Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

Maven fails to start spring-boot application through IntelliJ (and directly from command line). I am suspecting either dependency incompatibility or bad configuration. However, I am fairly new to Spring and can not seem to figure this one out. Guidance to how I can resolve this issue would be much appreciated.

**Stack trace**

```
[WARNING] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:478)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180)
at company.Config.main(Config.java:25)
... 6 more
```

**pom.xml**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>18.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdom2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20160810</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    ...ommited

</dependencies>
```

Comment: Look if you have another exception before this one.

Comment: You don't need this pedendency:<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

Answer (score 0):

Add below "dependecies" section, this:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I have *spring-boot-maven-plugin* as a build plugin with <goal>repackage</goal>